# Sensible and easy way of placing labels in ggplot with use of geom_dl and geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, label

I'm using the code below to generate a simple chart.

```
# Data import -------------------------------------------------------------

data(mtcars)
mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)

# Graph: Income Broadband -------------------------------------------------

# Lib.
require(ggplot2); require(directlabels)

# Graph definition
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, colour = "black", size = 3, fill = "black") +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = TRUE, fullrange = TRUE) +
  geom_dl(aes(label = model), list("smart.grid", cex = 0.5, hjust = -.5)) +
  xlab("MPG") +
  ylab("DISP") +
  theme_bw()
```

As illustrated below, the labels on the chart are placed far away from the points. I would like to amend this and place the point labels closer to the points on the graph. Naturally, for the sake of readability I would like for the labels not overlap. In addition, I would like for the solution to be easy to reproduce as I will have to apply across a number of charts. `mlabvpos` in Stata, as discussed [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-08/msg01170.html),  provides some of those functionalities. I'm looking for a similar solution in R.

[image: Labels]

## Edit

Following the comments, it appears the problem is not associated with the `hjust` settings. For instance, for the code:

```
# Graph definition
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, colour = "black", size = 3, fill = "black") +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = TRUE, fullrange = TRUE) +
  geom_dl(aes(label = model), list("smart.grid", cex = 0.5, hjust = -.001)) +
  xlab("MPG") +
  ylab("DISP") +
  theme_bw()
```

The labels are still misplaced:
[image: Attempt with new hjust settings]
On the same lines, running the code with no `hjust` settings does not place the labels in a more sensible manner:
[image: No hjust scatter]

Comment: cant you just change the hjust to something smaller

Comment: @rawr I don't think this is the case. Even with the `hjust = -.01` the labels are misplaced.

Comment: I think this has to do with the function you use for placement (`smart.grid`). If I replace that by `visualcenter` and remove the `hjust`, the labels are placed on the centers of the points. Of course, this is not what you want, but it illustrates that the labels may be place on the points. Maybe, `smart.grid` is not all that smart...

Comment: @Sitbu thanks for showing the interest, my hope was that `smart.grid` would solve my problem of non-overlapping labels. I'm happy to use another method, just whatever delivers the desired effect.